# Mongoose Not Enforcing Unique

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this schema.  It is not enforcing uniqueness in the zipCode field.  It was working at some point before I implemented the timestamps but doesn't seem to be now.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  I have tried dropping the DB but even all new additions are allowing duplicates.

```
    const ZipCodeSchema = new Schema({
    zipCode: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        index: true
    },
    price: {
        type: Currency,
        min: 0,
        required: true
    },
    createdBy: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Users',
        required: true
    },
    updatedBy: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Users',
        required: true
    },
    active: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true,
    },
    neighborhood: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    }
},
{
    timestamps: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

At some point, either manually or as part of your install / startup script, you need to [make sure the indexes are created](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.ensureIndexes) on your mongodb instance.  One way is with the `ensureIndexes` method

```
ZipCode.ensureIndexes(function (err) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [mongoose-unique-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-unique-validator) plugin for the pre-save validation of the unique `zipCode` field of `ZipCodeSchema`.

```
ZipCodeSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator, { type: 'mongoose-unique-validator' });
```